# Get the following error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in E:\AppServ\www\test.php on line 231"

Tags: php, jquery, sql, html

As title says Ii get this error when I try to integrate jplayer into a file manager script I purchased. Any help would be appreciated.
Here comes the code

```
 $files_table[$rN["id"]] .= "<td>
        <div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>

        <!-- Using the cssSelectorAncestor option with the default cssSelector class names to enable control association of standard functions using built in features -->

        <div id="jp_container" class="demo-container">
            <ul>
                <li><span>Select a track : </span></li>
                <li><a href=""download.php?path=".$rr["path"]."\" class="track track-default">".$rr["title"]."</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                <span class="play-state"></span> :
                <span class="track-name">nothing</span>
                at <span class="extra-play-info"></span>
                of <span class="jp-duration"></span>, which is
                <span class="jp-current-time"></span>
            </p>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="jp-play" href="#">Play</a></li>
                <li><a class="jp-pause" href="#">Pause</a></li>
                <li><a class="jp-stop" href="#">Stop</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>volume :</li>
                <li><a class="jp-mute" href="#">Mute</a></li>
                <li><a class="jp-unmute" href="#">Unmute</a></li>
                <li> <a class="jp-volume-bar" href="#">|&lt;----------&gt;|</a></li>
                <li><a class="jp-volume-max" href="#">Max</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</td>";
```

The error arrives at the first  tag.

Comment: You have a mass of " within your quoted string..... escape them.... or use HEREDOC or similar

Comment: Heeeeerrre comes the code! lol. This is a basic syntax fault that should be obvious to fix, and will be of no help to anyone else ever.

Answer (score 2):

How is this valid PHP:

```
"<td>   <div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>"
```

Surely you mean one of the following:

```
// print the content of $jquery_jplayer variable, if it exists, inside the id.
"<td>   <div id=\"".$jquery_jplayer."\"></div>" 

// print the string "jquery_jplayer" - notice the quotes are escaped
"<td>   <div id=\"jquery_jplayer\"></div>" 

// print the content of the variable + escaping the quotes
"<td>   <div id=\"$jquery_jplayer\"></div>"
```

Comment: Those are classes and ids, not PHP variables. There's nothing wrong there if all he needs do is assign a class/id.

Comment: @Scott so the second option...

Comment: @lucian.. yeah if the rest of the quotes were correct. There's a mix of improper quoting in the code though.

Comment: @Scott all over the place. But if he can't figure the rest on his own, given one of them... that's pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see by the colors in the stackoverflow code view, you're not escaping the double quotes.

If you want to use a `"` in a string that's delimited by `"`, you have to escape it. It then becomes a `\"`

[Wikipedia article on escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)

Comment: Thanks:) Ive learned something new. Im a noob when it comes to php

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Scape all the " from your HTML, because is messing with the string structure.
2. Have your string start and end with ' instead of "

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an error with quotes....

It's assumed that $files_table[$rN['id']] already has a value since you are concatenating to that variable via .=

If $files_table[$rN['id']] does not have a value, remove the dot in front of the =

```
$files_table[$rN['id']] .= '

    <!-- Using the cssSelectorAncestor option with the default cssSelector class names to enable control association of standard functions using built in features -->

    <div id="jp_container" class="demo-container">
        <ul>
            <li><span>Select a track : </span></li>
            <li><a href="download.php?path='.$rr['path'].'" class="track track-default">'.$rr['title'].'</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <span class="play-state"></span> :
            <span class="track-name">nothing</span>
            at <span class="extra-play-info"></span>
            of <span class="jp-duration"></span>, which is
            <span class="jp-current-time"></span>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="jp-play" href="#">Play</a></li>
            <li><a class="jp-pause" href="#">Pause</a></li>
            <li><a class="jp-stop" href="#">Stop</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>volume :</li>
            <li><a class="jp-mute" href="#">Mute</a></li>
            <li><a class="jp-unmute" href="#">Unmute</a></li>
            <li> <a class="jp-volume-bar" href="#">|&lt;----------&gt;|</a></li>
            <li><a class="jp-volume-max" href="#">Max</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
';
```